# Is it possible to use a custom web template inhirited from teamsite template, in a publish site template?

Tags: site-template, web-template, team-sites

I am using sharepoint 2010 and VS2010.

I have implemented this tutorial for creating a custom web template, and it works:

http://usmanmughal.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/how-to-create-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010-using-feature/

I have used/copied the teamsite template like in this tutorial to  my custom web template.

I am wondering if the following is possible:

I create a site collection from the site template "Publish Site".

In this site collection I create a sub site and select my custom web template (inherited from a teamsite template).

Is this ok, or not possible?

These are my custom web template files:

defaultdws.aspx (I copied this file from the teamsite site template)

default.aspx (I copied this file from the teamsite site template)

ONET.xml (I copied this file from the teamsite site template)

elements.xml (Here I inherit from the teamsite site template: BaseTemplateID="1" BaseTemplateName="STS" BaseConfigurationID="0")

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: I have already yet a site collection from the site template "publishing site", but I would like to create a custom webtemplate inherited from the site template "teamsite". I am afraid this is not compatible.

Comment: You can always activate publsihing features on a Teamsite or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,

Add `/_Layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx` at end of your publishing site URL, it will take you to  `Page Layout and Site Template Settings` which can be used to create a team site template as sub-site of publishing site.

OR

> Go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Look And Feel > Page Layout and
>   Site template.
>
> Select the list of templates you want.

[Source](http://geekswithblogs.net/GinoAbraham/archive/2011/05/20/add-team-site-under-publishing-site-as-a-subsite.aspx)